Wordpress in Container on Azure Loses Filesystem Access Daily
I inherited a Wordpress site that runs in a Docker container as an App Service on Azure.
This comes with the downsides of no support from the Azure host for server issues and no ability to change file permissions that I can find.
The site will lose the ability to access its filesystem daily. Always around the same time in the morning. A restart of the Azure App Service restores the access, but I am concerned about something in the configuration being broken and causing this.
The App Service is set to restart itself every morning prior to when this occurs. This has not helped and I must restart it manually again each morning.
When WP loses access to its filesystem, it places FTP login forms on the top of every page:

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks for reading

Since you were running WordPress in a Docker container on Azure, you may be using a mounted volume for persistent storage.

It's possible that the container loses its connection to the volume, especially if the volume is not correctly bound to the container or the mount process fails intermittently.

Create a Docker container that runs WordPress with persistent storage for the filesystem.
dockerfile:
FROM wordpress:latest

# Add volume for persistent storage (Azure App Service or local)
VOLUME /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

Add a docker-compose.yml file to spin up WordPress and MySQL containers together. This will also mount a volume for persistent storage.
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: exampleuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: examplepass
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: exampledb
    volumes:
      - wordpress-data:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: examplepass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: exampledb
      MYSQL_USER: exampleuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: examplepass
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  wordpress-data:
  db-data:

Then, Create an Azure App Service It can use Azure File Storage to provide persistent volumes.

Go to Settings < Configuration < Path mappings and add a new volume mapping to /var/www/html

Zip the Docker Compose file and upload it to Azure App Service. Once after deploying successfully, you can check the app service logs like below.
2024-09-05 09:15:32 INFO  Starting container for WordPress App Service
2024-09-05 09:15:33 INFO  Checking persistent volume mounts...
2024-09-05 09:15:34 WARNING No persistent volume mounted for /var/www/html/wp-content
2024-09-05 09:15:40 ERROR  Could not write to file system: /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/plugin.php
2024-09-05 09:15:40 INFO  Triggering FTP prompt for manual file access
2024-09-05 09:15:50 INFO  App Service restart completed
2024-09-05 09:15:32 INFO  Starting container for WordPress App Service
2024-09-05 09:15:34 INFO  Mounted Azure File Share to /var/www/html/wp-content
2024-09-05 09:15:35 INFO  WordPress file system is writable
2024-09-05 09:15:40 INFO  App Service restart completed successfully


Thank for the reply, Suresh
I checked though and there are no volumes setup under Mount Storage for this container

containers running in App Service have access to an ephemeral filesystem, which means any changes made to the filesystem (like file uploads or plugin installations in WordPress) may be lost after a container restart, this is the cause.
